# Scroll user to clicked tab on mobile with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I created a tabular system with jquery click for my website on mobile.

Here is the working example with my structure and js code https://jsfiddle.net/anahitdev/6u7s1wa4/

```
jQuery('.aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn').each(function(){ 
    jQuery(this).click(function(){
        jQuery('.aboutSectionMobileRow').removeClass('activeAboutMobileSlide');
        jQuery('.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom').slideUp();
        if(!jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom').is(':visible')){
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().addClass('activeAboutMobileSlide');
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom').slideDown('fast', function(){
                jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery('.aboutSectionMobileRow.activeAboutMobileSlide').find('.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom .aboutSectionIconWrap').offset().top - jQuery('.mobileMenuWrap').outerHeight()
                }, 1000);
            });
        }else{ 
            jQuery('.aboutSectionMobileRow').removeClass('activeAboutMobileSlide');
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom').slideUp();
        }  
    });
});
```

It is not leading to exact scrolling position of clicked/active tab.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are a bunch of problems with your code

the code is very messy and hard to read / understand. i strongly suggest you cache your selectors ( use variables ) . plus the html it's very confusing, a lot of div's and long name classes , It's not optimal to write it like this.

there is no need of an `each()` method which causes an unnecessary loop

instead of `.parent().parent()` you can use `.parents()` because as it says in the DOC's : `The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree`

anyway, i changed a bit your code and now it's working as you want. check it out below in snippet or in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6u7s1wa4/5/)

```js
var readmore = $('.aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn'),
  menuHeight = $(".mobileMenuWrap").outerHeight()


$(readmore).on("click", function() {
  var thisParent = $(this).parents(".aboutSectionMobileRow"),
    thisText = $(thisParent).find('.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom'),
    scrollTo = $(thisParent).offset().top - menuHeight


  $(thisParent).removeClass('activeAboutMobileSlide');
  $(thisText).slideUp();

  if (!$(thisText).is(':visible')) {
    $(thisParent).addClass('activeAboutMobileSlide');

    $(thisText).slideDown('fast')

    $('html, body').animate({

      scrollTop: scrollTo
    }, 1000);

  } else {
    $(thisParent).removeClass('activeAboutMobileSlide');
    $(thisText).slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
.mobileMenuWrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.mobileMenuBg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1b1b2d;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.mobileMenuInner {
  width: 90%;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRows {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 66px 0;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRow {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #464667;
  padding: 14px 0;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRow:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowTop {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowTitle {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'kontrapunktbold';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ec3d5c;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn {
  width: 29%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 11px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnTextWrap {
  width: 65%;
  float: none;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnText {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'kontrapunktbold';
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonWrap {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.iosDevice .aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonWrap {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonLine {
  width: 24px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligon {
  width: 9px;
  height: 8px;
  background: url(images/button_hexagon_white.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn:hover .aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligon {
  -webkit-animation: color-me-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: color-me-in 1s;
  -ms-animation: color-me-in 1s;
  -o-animation: color-me-in 1s;
  animation: color-me-in 1s;
}

.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobileMenuWrap">
  <div class="mobileMenuBg"></div>
  <div class="mobileMenuInner">
    <div class="mobileMenuBtn">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mobileMenuLogo">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="aboutSectionMobileRows">
  <div class="aboutSectionMobileRow">
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowTop">
      <h4 class="aboutSectionMobileRowTitle">Who are We</h4>
      <a class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn">
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnTextWrap">
               <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnText">Read More</span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonWrap">
                   <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonLine"></span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligon"></span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowBottom">
      <div class="aboutSectionIconWrap">
        <div class="aboutSectionMobileAnimatedFigure">
          <div class="aboutSLideAnimatedMobileArea" style="background:url('http://imaginawp.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/uploads/Desk_500x500_48frames.png');background-size:100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="aboutSectionMobileTextWrap">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aboutSectionMobileRow">
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowTop">
      <h4 class="aboutSectionMobileRowTitle">Our Vision</h4>
      <a class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn">
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnTextWrap">
               <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnText">Read More</span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonWrap">
                   <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonLine"></span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligon"></span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowBottom">
      <div class="aboutSectionIconWrap">
        <div class="aboutSectionMobileAnimatedFigure">
          <div class="aboutSLideAnimatedMobileArea" style="background:url('http://imaginawp.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/uploads/spider_49_500-min.png');background-size:100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="aboutSectionMobileTextWrap">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aboutSectionMobileRow">
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowTop">
      <h4 class="aboutSectionMobileRowTitle">Our History</h4>
      <a class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn">
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnTextWrap">
               <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnText">Read More</span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonWrap">
                   <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonLine"></span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligon"></span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowBottom">
      <div class="aboutSectionIconWrap">
        <div class="aboutSectionMobileAnimatedFigure">
          <div class="aboutSLideAnimatedMobileArea" style="background:url('http://imaginawp.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/uploads/Book_500x500_72-min.png');background-size:100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="aboutSectionMobileTextWrap">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aboutSectionMobileRow">
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowTop">
      <h4 class="aboutSectionMobileRowTitle">Why Work With Us</h4>
      <a class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtn">
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnTextWrap">
               <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowReadmoreBtnText">Read More</span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonWrap">
                   <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligonLine"></span>
        <span class="aboutSectionMobileRowAnimatedPoligon"></span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutSectionMobileRowBottom">
      <div class="aboutSectionIconWrap">
        <div class="aboutSectionMobileAnimatedFigure">
          <div class="aboutSLideAnimatedMobileArea" style="background:url('http://imaginawp.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/uploads/hi5_48_450-min.png');background-size:100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="aboutSectionMobileTextWrap">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thank you for the smippet. Yes i agree with you and will note your comments. And yes you were rigth that excluding the menu height was causing teh problem but i need it to be excluded cause i have fixed positioned menu so what i can do here @Mihai T

Comment: if you could share the entire HTML code ( including the `mobileMenuwrap ` ) maybe i could help

Comment: I did just like that but still the issue exists. I guess i found the issue. In my code i have this line jQuery('.aboutSectionMobileRowBottom').slideUp(); which hides the opened all tabs and open only the current one. That's seems to be my main issue. Any idea how i can achive only one tab to be open in another way @Mihai T? Thank you

Comment: I even tried with hide but it has the same effect. What else i missed @Mihai T?

Comment: sorry. got a bunch of stuff to do :) here's the quick fix i came up with https://jsfiddle.net/6u7s1wa4/7/

Comment: ooh quite good workaround. Thank you very much @Mihai T. If i would have chance will upvote once more :)